# I have a date & time in a cell I want to trim down to just a time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

In cell G8 I have "14/10/2019 17:09:45". How can I trim this with google app script down to just "17:09:45". Ill show below what I have tried.

I want to ultimately compare multiple times without the dates, but currently all of my data is in the same format as "14/10/2019 17:09:45".

Thanks.

```
function a() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var daily_data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Daily Data");  //Gets the date & time from sheet "Daily Data"...
  var date_time = daily_data.getRange('G8').getDisplayValue();     //...in cell G8 ("14/10/2019 17:09:45").
  var time = date_time.slice(11)   //Removes the date (ie. the first 11 characters) from the string "14/10/2019 17:09:45".
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').setValue(time);    //Should paste just the time into cell A1. But does not work.

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `getDisplayValue()` instead, as `getValues()` returns a 2D array with a JavaScript date object inside:

```
var date_time = daily_data.getRange('G8').getDisplayValue();
```

Comment: I’ve tried this but still no luck. See my updated script.

Comment: @Nag Explain terms like  .. *no luck*.., .. *doesn't work*... in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure what you mean :S I’m quite new to scripting. 

By ‘no luck’ I meant that switching it to instead get the display value didn’t work for some reason. Apologies is this is obvious & cheers for the help.

Comment: @Nag what do you mean "doesn't work"? Read [mre](Specifically,  the part under: **Reproducible title: bullet point 1**, but read everything else carefully too)

Comment: I meant it doesn’t put the time (without the date) into cell A1. What part of my code is unecessary? My original was much larger and this was my attempt at a minimal reproducible example. Any advice on what parts are unecessary to my example? I think it’s all needed to show what I’m attempting to achieve. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Nag You mean it puts the date & time of G8 in A1?i.e., without slicing? I didn't say it's not minimal. The link provides valuable debug points, which if you follow, will help a long way. Also, When G8 is looks like `14/10/2019 17:09:45`, I get A1 as `17:09:45`. So, it's not reproducible.